# regex to clean badly formatted JSON with internal quotations within a string

Tags: r, json, string

I'm using a GPT to return topics within a text. It's working surprisingly well, however, occasionally the LLM will provide a quote within the answer (despite being asked not to!).

I'm sure there must be a way to remove these quotes with a regex but I'm afraid it's beyond my experience to know where to start.

In the example below the `refactory` has been quoted and therefore breaks the JSON when I try to convert it.

Any help or pointers would be gratefully appreciated. I'm working in R but regex is *fairly* universal.

```
json_obj <– '{"topic_name": "refractory",
    "topic_note_count": 2,
    "topic_description": "The use of the term "refractory" to describe infections that do not respond to standard antiviral therapies."
  }'

jsonlite::fromJSON(json_obj)

#Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
#          tion": "The use of the term "refractory" to describe inf
#                     (right here) ------^
```

Comment: Do you always get the text output in the format as you have shown? Every key-value is located on a single line? Also note there is no such a thing as "universal regex", in R, there are already 4 regex flavors used, and they are quite different from one another.

Comment: I realise they're not universal, but as I'm not sure even how to start I thought it best to take any answer and convert it as necessary. And yes the format shown is how it always comes out.

Comment: How are you building the JSON data from the chatGPT response? It would be better to make a correct file the first time than clean it up later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on the structure of your json. I'd be wary of constructing a regex that tries to identify nested quotes, as you quickly get into [this kind of territory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns):

> A finite automaton (which is the data structure underlying a regular expression) does not have memory apart from the state it's in, and if you have arbitrarily deep nesting, you need an arbitrarily large automaton, which collides with the notion of a finite automaton.

However, if your data looks similar to above I'd just remove the opening and closing brace and use R's `read.table()` with the `:` as separator, which is pretty flexible with handling quotes:

```r
dat <- gsub("^\\{|\\s+\\}$", "", json_obj) |>
    read.table(text = _, sep = ":", col.names = c("keys", "vals"))
#                    keys                                                                                                        vals
# 1            topic_name                                                                                                 refractory,
# 2      topic_note_count                                                                                                          2,
# 3     topic_description  The use of the term refractory to describe infections that do not respond to standard antiviral therapies.
```

This will give you an extra comma but you can remove that by including it in the `whitespace` argument of [`trimws()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/trimws.html), which we need to use anyway to remove the spaces caused by indentation.

```r
dat$vals |>
    trimws(whitespace = "[\\s,]") |>
    as.list() |>
    setNames(trimws(dat$keys)) |>
    jsonlite::toJSON(pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
{
  "topic_name": "refractory",
  "topic_note_count": "2",
  "topic_description": "The use of the term refractory to describe infections that do not respond to standard antiviral therapies."
}
```

Of course once the data is in R you may not need to convert it back to a json, in which case you could stop after you have trimmed the whitespace and commas from your `data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you, that's some out of the box thinking! You're right, I'm using JSON to make moving the data to a data.frame easy and your solution bypasses the fault within the outputs I have :-)